# ajax call fail in Cordova app on real device but works fine in the emulator

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, visual-studio-cordova

I've developed a mobile app using cordova platform ,it just work fine in ripple simulator but if i try to on real device(android) using USB cable then it throw error on ajax call ?it seems repeated question but i've tried all the sugestion found on googling which don't work for me.

//my ajax call code

```
$("#loginButton").off().click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            var data = JSON.stringify({
                PortalID: 1,
                UserName: $('#txtuserName').val(),
                Password: $('#txtpassword').val(),
            });
           $.ajax({
               contentType:  "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               type: 'POST',    
               url:'http://192.168.01.10:8043/BackEndWebService/LoginWebService.asmx/LoginUser',
               dataType: 'json',
               data:data,
               success: function(result){
              alert (result)     
            },
              error: function(error){
              alert("error");
          }
            });
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: @Phonolog no errors in cosole

Comment: change this (url:'http://192.168.01.10:8043/) to your wan IP address and change virtual server on your router to direct HTTP traffic to  192.168.01.10. port 8043 -- see if that helps, maybe its a CORS issue but then again you may not debug the app properly  -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Are you building from inside Visual Studio? have you tried bulding from the commandline?  I noticed a difference because I could make calls to my services when building with the Visual Studio stack.

Comment: In your error handler, where you currently show "alert("error")" can you set a breakpoint in the debugger and is there any message in the error parameter passed to that function?